# Default function arguments have global scope leading to unexpected behavior

Tags: python

I have a simple python question.  Consider the following code.

```
import random

def int_list(local_list=[]):
    local_list.append(random.randint(0,1000))
    return local_list

for i in range(5):
    print(int_list())
```

Under both python2 and python3 the result is:

```
>> [828]
>> [828, 268]
>> [828, 268, 999]
>> [828, 268, 999, 471]
>> [828, 268, 999, 471, 847]
```

I would have expected the following result instead:

```
>> [828]
>> [268]
>> [999]
>> [471]
>> [847]
```

Apparently the object used to instantiate local_list has global scope and is the same for every invocation.  Not only does this surprise me, but it also seems like incorrect or at least undesirable behavior.  I assume this question has been raised before.  Can someone point me to a rationale?

Comment: Thanks John, my question is answered by the one you linked to.

Comment: It is the third question in the `Related` list on the right.  (BTW, I was the one who found it ;)